# How to get params from encoded current URL?

Tags: php

Encoded URL

```
www.example.com/apps/?bmFtZTE9QUhTRU4mbmFtZTI9TUFFREEmcGVyY2VudD02NQ
```

Decoded URL

```
www.example.com/apps/?name1=AHSEN&name2=MAEDA&percent=65
```

now i want to get params from encoded URL

```
ob_start();
$name1 = $_GET['name1'];
```

Comment: You should get name1 value inside $name1 correctly based on the example you have provided. What is your problem statement?

Comment: i'm getting params from the decoded url with the example above, but i can't get params  in encoded url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have the decoded url somewhere in a variable. If you extract the query part from it (the part after the `?`), you can feed that query string to the function [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).

If you use `parse_str` with just the query string as argument, it sets the appropriate variables automatically. For example

```
// whereever you get the query part of your decoded url from
$my_query_string = "name1=AHSEN&name2=MAEDA&percent=65";
// feed it into parse_str
parse_str($my_query_string);
```

would set the global variables

```
$name1
$name2
$percent
```

But I'd advise to make use of the second parameter that `parse_str` offers, because it provides you with better control. For that, provide `parse_str` with an array as second parameter. Then the function will set the variables from your query string as entries in that array, analogous to what you know from `$_GET`.

```
// whereever you get the query part of your decoded url from
$my_query_string = "name1=AHSEN&name2=MAEDA&percent=65";
// provide parse_str with the query string *and* an array you want the results in
parse_str($my_query_string, $query_vars);

echo $query_vars['name1']; // should print out "AHSEN"
```

UPDATE: To split your complete decoded url, you can use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

Comment: how to replace query part of  the current url in $my_query_string?

Comment: As I said, you probably get the decoded url from somewhere. That's your part of the task, I don't know the system your working on ;) Once you've got the decoded url in a variable, you can use parse_url to get the query part. Then you can use parse_str on the query part.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php).

This should get you started...

```
<?php
  $query = "my=apples&are=green+and+red";

  foreach (explode('&', $query) as $chunk) {
     $param = explode("=", $chunk);

     if ($param) {
        printf("Value for parameter \"%s\" is \"%s\"<br/>\n",
          urldecode($param[0]), urldecode($param[1]));
     }
  }
?>
```

Comment: can you provide me the example here ?

Comment: is this possible that i place encoded line from the url in $query and then get decoded params ? @peter

Comment: my URL changes params on every load.. so i want that params not a params that i set in the code